# Mysql indexing for table with multiple filtering option

Tags: mysql, performance, hibernate, optimization, query-optimization

My application is developed using Spring, hibernate using Mysql DB.
We have a table called company in which we have around 20 columns. We have a search/filter screen with multiple options so search company records. for example say the table has column A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I, J, K, L, M etc. There are three columns say C, D & E which goes with every search query, but there can be any combination of rest of the columns or none in the where clause.
We are trying to create index on the company table so that it can consume all the multiple combinations of search query. 
Please suggest if it is possible to create indexes which can optimize searches with various columns and if yes how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"There are three columns say C, D & E which goes with every search query" -- So have a composite index that includes those 3 columns.  It may not be worth adding any more columns to the index.

To discuss this further, please use actual column names and actual `WHERE` clause examples.  There are far too many caveats to stop at the simplified answer in my above paragraph.